# Is there a reason why PHP does not catch this substring?

Tags: php, substring

I have an array with a bunch of strings, some of which contain the following code:

```
<SPAN style="font:7.0pt &quot;Times New Roman&quot;"> </SPAN>
```

When I try to do a

```
str_replace("<SPAN style=\"font:7.0pt &quot;Times New Roman&quot;\"> </SPAN>","",$var);
```

It does not get caught.

Any ideas why not?

Comment: May be because of spaces

Comment: Is `$var` the array? You have to loop through the array and perform the replace with individual strings.

Comment: well, i'm simply copying the original substring and escaping the quotation marks. Why would there be a problem with spaces?

Comment: Juhana, no, $var is the actual string taken out of the array

Comment: It works for me. Have you forgot to assign or echo new value? `str_replace` does not perform in-place replacement, it returns new value instead.

Comment: It works for me.  Are you sure the string is completely identical?  I would try cutting down the length of `<SPAN style=\"font:7.0pt &quot;Times New Roman&quot;\"> </SPAN>` in your `str_replace` to find out where it is going wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that original string's right (Seems a bit odd; I'd have expected `<SPAN style="font:7.0pt 'Times New Roman'"> </SPAN>`, without the odd `&quot;`.) Is it maybe being escaped by something when you're displaying it? Where's it coming from? Can we see a bit more of your code please, including any code you used to dump that array of strings to check the content?

Comment: rahul, it looks like you are right. what i did is I started replacing character by character, and the string IS caught right up to <SPAN style=\"font:7.0pt &quot;Times New Roman&quot;\">

It is as soon as I put that one extra space that the hell breaks loose. But the problem is, the space I copy from the original string. How could it not work that way?

Comment: @unomyname Is it maybe a tab that's being converted to a space by your editor, or something? Maybe you should be using `preg_replace` and checking for generic whitespace instead. Might be safer.

Answer (score 3):

Function str_replace **returns** the replaced string, so you must do:

```
$var=str_replace("<SPAN style=\"font:7.0pt &quot;Times New Roman&quot;\"> </SPAN>","",$var);
```

**EDIT**: But you should consider using strip_tags() or preg_replace(), for instance like this:

```
$var=preg_replace('#<span( [^>]+)?>(.*)</span>#iu','\\2',$var)
```

(replaces all  tags and closing tags - I haven't tested, test before using)

Comment: that's what i'm doing, i just pasted the function for the simplicity's sake. it does not catch the instance

Comment: I once spent half an hour once just watching that single line, trying to figure out why it wouldn't replace the string until it dawned to me. I'll never forget this "trick". ;)

Comment: @unomyname: then you should check that all the characters are the same. Can't help you from this example though as this one works. BTW, you should consider using strip_tags() or preg_replace() - I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the formatting in $var for the string you are searching is different. I tried this:

```
$var = 'dsfdsfdsf<SPAN style="font:7.0pt &quot;Times New Roman&quot;"> </SPAN>idshfudsyfuisdfy';

echo str_replace("<SPAN style=\"font:7.0pt &quot;Times New Roman&quot;\"> </SPAN>","",$var);
```

It outputs `dsfdsfdsfidshfudsyfuisdfy`

I would suggest you output $var and check if it really is what you expect.

Comment: is there a way to output $var other than by 

    echo htmlspecialchars($var)

so that it shows every darn character as is?

Comment: @unomyname It can be problematic dumping strings containing HTML to an HTML document. If it's all you're outputting, or just for testing, try converting your document to text on output -- before you output *anything else*, use `header("Content-Type: text/plain");`. That'll tell the browser to interpret your document as plain text. Then just `echo`ing or `var_dump`ing `$var` should be easier.

Comment: var_dump($var). Then view the page source(Ctrl+U).

Comment: after long and painful investigation, it turned out that the character is a CR, not the space. Who would have thought...